# Next.js Head ignores duplicate Meta Tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using these Meta Tags with different media-targets in the Head of my Next.js project:

```js
<Head>
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#7f8fa6"/>
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="#141414" />
</Head>
```

Unfortunately, only the last of these meta tags is then rendered on the page, which is in this case the one for the dark-mode.

I'm aware I could use Javascript, but this seems like there should be another way around. Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure? In sandbox works fine https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/busy-blackwell-0j4syp?file=%2Fpages%2F_document.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A13%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A18%2C%22startColumn%22%3A13%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A18%7D%5D.

There 2 tags.

Maybe need to add more code examples, maybe problems is somewhere else.

And if you follow the documentation, you should to add key property.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head

Comment: You were right about the key property! With two different key properties, it works fine.

`
<Head>
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#7f8fa6" key="light" />
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="#141414" key="dark" />
</Head>
`